# 'Broken' condition in Chronicles of Darkness: should I note what I would have rolled without the penalty?

Tags: conditions, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

The text of the condition 'Broken (Persistent)' (Core rulebook, p288) reads (my emphasis):

> Whatever you did or saw, something inside you snapped. You can barely muster up the will to do your job anymore, and anything more emotionally intense than a raised voice makes you flinch and back down. Apply a -2 to all Social rolls and rolls involving Resolve, and a -5 to any use of the
>   Intimidation Skill.
>
> **Resolution**: You back down from a confrontation or fail a roll **due to this Condition**. If you regain a dot of Integrity, lose another dot of Integrity, or achieve an exceptional success on a breaking point, you can shed this Condition.

Does this mean that I should roll the dice I lose due to the penalty separately to see if they would have lead to a success instead, and only shed the condition when the 'real' roll is a fail while the 'lost' roll would have changed the outcome to a success?

Comment: My version of the text doesn't say that. I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that, of course, but that's going beyond the call of duty. It's reasonable to interpret that as "When you fail a roll that this condition penalizes…" The fiction should, of course, reflect that your broken spirit has led you to this state.

However, **that text has been changed in later printings**. Failing a roll or backing down from a conflict ***gives you a Beat***. It doesn't resolve the condition — that's limited to when you "regain a dot of Integrity, lose another dot of Integrity, or achieve an exceptional success on a breaking point."

Comment: Wow, the revision makes the condition even more, uhm, intense than it already turned out in our game. (We did indeed rule to resolve it on the first failed roll, regardless of 'lost' dice.) This looks like the answer, but I'll leave the question open for a while longer to give others the chance to weigh in.